# Terraform aws_s3_bucket_object, Call to function "filemd5" failed: open <file>

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My `index.html` is in the same level of where my terraform resource file is located

```
terraform
│       └── site
│           ├── index.html
│           ├── s3.tf
│           └── variables.tf
```

My config looks like this

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "index" {
  key    = "index.html"
  acl = "public-read"
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.my_example_site.id
  source = "index.html"
  etag = filemd5("index.html")
}
```

When I apply, I get this error

```
│ Error: Error in function call
│
│   on modules/terraform/site/s3.tf line 15, in resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "index":
│   15:   etag = filemd5("index.html")
│
│ Call to function "filemd5" failed: open index.html: no such file or directory.
```

Comment: Can you try with `etag = filemd5("${path.module}/index.html")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a proper reference to your path. You're running terraform out of your root, not the module. Thus as the comments suggest, you need to you `${path.module}` to properly tell terraform where the file is.